# Error while trying to run WordCount program using hadoop-yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

When I am trying to run WordCount program on cluster node I am getting error as mentioned below. Can anyone suggest solution to this issue?

```
ava.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -60 namespaceID = 1055173391 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-5d8c37db-fb42-416f-a179-3e7ff1690690 ; blockpoolId = BP-1781828547-192.168.104.173-1443620560920.
Expecting respectively: -60; 1665606821; 0; CID-6ec1fbb1-3515-4eca-9f55-2dbe8417b7e5; BP-555346680-192.168.104.173-1443500187475.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:357)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I have edited your question and improved formatting to help understand it better. It would be great if you can add the code from which you are getting exception

Comment: You have conflicts with Hadoop Namenode Block pool ID and DataNode Block Pool ID. If you don't any data in the hadoop. Its better to format Namenode and restart ahdoop cluster